# compare saved GPS (Latitude , Longitude) points with current GPS (Latitude , Longitude) points?

Tags: android, gps, location, sharedpreferences

i want that when i click button it save the current location of gps coordinate with shared preference and also want to compare that gps coordinate with new coordinate when location is changed ( onLocationChanged event ) Who is the best way to do this ??

Comment: what did you try and what complications are you having with it?

Comment: Get the current location, get the original location, and use subtraction to see how much they changed by.  If more than some threshold, count it as changed.  Location.distanceTo might help somewhat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use an sql oracle function as below to calculate distances:

```
create or replace
FUNCTION CALC_DISTANCE (Lat1 IN NUMBER,
                                     Lon1 IN NUMBER,
                                     Lat2 IN NUMBER,
                                     Lon2 IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS
 -- Convert degrees to radians
 DEGTORAD NUMBER := 57.29577951;
 Radius NUMBER := 6387.7;

BEGIN
  RETURN(NVL(Radius,0) * ACOS((sin(NVL(Lat1,0) / DegToRad) * SIN(NVL(Lat2,0) / DegToRad)) +
        (COS(NVL(Lat1,0) / DegToRad) * COS(NVL(Lat2,0) / DegToRad) *
         Cos(Nvl(Lon2,0) / Degtorad - Nvl(Lon1,0)/ Degtorad))));
END;
```

OR

You can probably use a select query as below in your sqlite db and get an output

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT (NVL(6387.7,0) * ACOS((sin(NVL(Lat1,0) / 57.29577951) * SIN(NVL(Lat2,0) / 57.29577951)) +
            (COS(NVL(Lat1,0) / 57.29577951) * COS(NVL(Lat2,0) / 57.29577951) *
             Cos(Nvl(Lon2,0) / 57.29577951 - Nvl(Lon1,0)/ 57.29577951))))";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Location's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) class `distanceTo(Location dest)` method to measure distance in meters between two locations.

From the [Developer guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29):

> Returns the approximate distance in meters between this location and
>   the given location. Distance is defined using the WGS84 ellipsoid.